# how do i write certain commands and call them into a page in php

Tags: php, class

I have a page that is using alot of mysql queries.
Is there a way i can write one php file and call these queries into any page ?

Example :
Lets say i have 50 of the below queries in a php file (there are 50 different queries)

---

```
<?php
     include_once("db.php");

      session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['affID'])) {

}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(AffPaid) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "£" . $row['c'] ; 

?>
```

---

Can i not do the following ?

```
**$query1 =**

<?php
     include_once("db.php");

      session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['affID'])) {

}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(AffPaid) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "£" . $row['c'] ;
```

then in any page say echo $query1 ?

Comment: You can define [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) to do your queries, or you can use [object oriented structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) to further encapsulate things. Put these definitions in a separate file, use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to load them, and then call the ones you need.

Comment: If you have a page with 50 individual sql queries, you are probably doing something wrong

Comment: I am working with about 20 different tables and over 18000 different entries in each table.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer. Also You should remain available for at least 30 min with the question open in your browser so we can get clarification on your question if it's needed. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to wrap each query in a function:

```
<?php
    function query1() {
        include_once("db.php");

        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['affID'])) {

        }

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(AffPaid) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo "£" . $row['c'] ;
    }
?>
```

Then where you want it to be shown include:

```
<?php
    query1();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I believe you're asking (it's not terribly clear) is if you can assign the entire content of a php page to a php variable. The answer is no.

But to accomplish what you're trying to do just use an `include` like so:

query.php:

```
 <?php
 include_once("db.php");

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['affID'])) { //I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here?

}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(AffPaid) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . $_SESSION['affID'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "£" . $row['c'] ;
```

and then do this:

```
include_once("query.php");
```

in any file you want it in.

You can also encapsulate this into a function, but you'll still need to include the page as I've shown you.

**EDIT:**

According to your comment responses I think what you need to do is create a file like above, but it should look more like this:

query.php:

```
 <?php
 include_once("db.php");

function runQuery($queryString) {
    $result = mysql_query($queryString); // Missing connection
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return "£" . $row['c'] ;
}
```

and your calling file should have this:

```
include_once("query.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['affID'])) { 
   $result = runQuery("SELECT SUM(AffPaid) as c FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" . "_SESSION['affID'] . "'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you put, but you could put your code in the first example (the bit you say is repeated 50 times) and have that function saved in a file somewhere and then in any php file you use that code, include the file with the function in at the top and then call the function whenever you need to use that code

EDIT:

You could also run the code once and save the result to a global variable so it can be accessed everywhere (generally though, if you can avoid global variables then don't use them)

Comment: The code isnt actually repeated, there are 50 different sql queries and i need a name to call for each one

Comment: Ah right, how about a function that you pass some flag to (string or integer) and then do a switch statement on the flag and have each case perform a different query?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a PHP file like the example below:

**queries.php**

```
<?php
$query[0] = "";
$query[1] = "";
...
```

And then `include()` it in your main PHP file and call it from there, like this:

```
include_once("queries.php");

$result = mysql_query($query[0]); // As you can see, $query[0] is in queries.php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "£" . $row['c'] ;
```

Comment: Do i then need to include the page that has all the $query that have been built ?

Comment: Yes, you have to include it, then you can use it everywhere in your script. Good luck.